# How to form JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I want my PHP code to echo a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "accounting": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": 23
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Mary",
      "lastName": "Smith",
      "age": 32
    }
  ]
}
```

How to do it in PHP?

Edit : I MEAN HOW TO FORM THIS TYPE OF JSON? My program is extracting these details from a table.

Something like this

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM details";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

  ????????????????????
  }
  echo json_encode(????);
?>
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($accountingArray);`

Comment: where is your php code??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php - very simple to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
$accounting = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $arr = array();
$arr["firstName"] = $row["firstName"];
$arr["lastName"] = $row["lastName"];
$arr["age"] = $row["age"];
array_push($accounting, $arr);
 }
 $data["accounting"] = $accounting
 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following PHP will result in the JSON you are looking for. Basically, create the corresponding PHP data structure using PHP arrays and associative arrays which will be converted to JSON arrays and objects.

```
$data = array(
  'accounting' => array(
    array(
      'firstName' => 'John',
      'lastName' => 'Doe',
      'age' => 23
    ),
    array(
      'firstName' => 'Mary',
      'lastName' => 'Smith',
      'age' => 32
    )
  )
);

$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks , but i dont have the predefined values . My program have to fetch the details from a database and then form this type of array. How to this in a loop or some other way

Comment: Assuming that each database row corresponds to a person, you can create an array `$data = array( 'accounting' => array() );` and use `array_push` to add each person on to the accounting array.

Answer (score 1):

use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

The first and only required Parameter is an array().
The array can also be multidimensional

The functions returns a string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode($array), then it will display the array in json format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output :
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}